# JQuery Datatable reload

Tags: jquery, datatable, reload

I'm trying to reload datatable. I click a cell and then an ajax request works. If it returns success, I need to reload the datatable with new data. I can see reload action "Processing" but new data doesn't seen in the table.

I'm using the same function in deleting process and it works.

Here is my code sample;

```
var dataTableId = "#dataTable";

function deleteFunction(){

// works correctly

}

$(dataTableId).dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": "url",
        "aoColumns": [
            ...
        ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [               
           ...    
       ]
});

    var table = $(dataTableId).DataTable();
    $('#dataTableFiles tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {

                 $.ajax({
                    url: "url",
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: postArray,
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.result) {
                            table.ajax.reload();
                        }
                        else {
                            table.ajax.reload();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("err")
                    }
                });    
    });
```

Thank you..

Comment: Can you tell us what is the verson of dataTable api that you're using?

Comment: Hi, "@version  1.10.0-dev"

Comment: did you see any error in browser-console?

Comment: No, I didn't see any error.Now I'm looking the new data. But it's correct.,

Comment: what is the url? in your question its `"url"` string. is it correct?

Comment: yes it's correct. url shows the way for a function in controller class

Answer (score 0):

try `table.api().ajax.reload();`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Make sure that that your function in controller class returns also the attribute sEcho. The sEcho is sent from the client in ajax request, then you have to capture this sEcho in your controller class and sent it back un-altered. So the json from the controller class can look like this
(where sEcho=10 is the value sent from the client).

```
 { 
        "iTotalRecords": 10,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 10,
        "sEcho":10,
        "aaData": [

        ]
    }
```